# Gmails OAUTH 2.0 without ServiceAccount

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail, mailkit, mimekit

I'm trying to send an Email with the OAUTH 2.0 authentication like this:

```
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\path\to\my.p12", "mypassword", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential
            .Initializer("my@id.gserviceaccount.com")
        {
            Scopes = new[] { "https://mail.google.com/" },
            User = "scm.beartung@gmail.com"
        }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        bool result = await credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);


        // send email
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
            client.Authenticate("user.name", credential.Token.AccessToken);
            client.Send(myMessage);
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
```

But when I'm running this code I get the TokenResponseException: "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."
Am I right that I need to authorize my client, what is only possible with a G Suit account? So I have to pay for an Admin account or remove the OAUTH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow [Google's instructions](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) for obtaining OAuth 2.0 credentials for your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when I followed the instructions at some point I got an error message that I don't had an admin account and I had to buy it. So I guess that's the only way to use the OAUTH 2.0?

Comment: Yes, that’s the only way to do it. I didn’t think it would actually cost money though.

Comment: Hm okay, guess i'll check that out again then. Thank you :)